# are there ways to find the number which is close to the avg entered numbers in arrays

Tags: c++, for-loop, math, numbers

So in this program the user enter numbers in the array and the program calculate the average of the numbers and which entered number is closer to the average , but the program doesn't print the closest number

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int tab[6] ;
    float sum = 0,b,s,mx=tab[1];
    
    for ( int i=0 ; i<6 ; i ++){
        cout << " Enter tab ["<<i<<"] : ";
        cin>>tab[i];
        }
    for ( int i=0 ; i<6 ; i++){
        sum=sum+tab[i];
        b=sum/6;
    }
    cout<<" the average of your numbers are : " << b << endl;
    for ( int i=0 ; i<6 ;i++){
        s=abs(tab[i]-b); 
        if(s<mx){
        mx=s;
        cout<<" the number much close to the avg is : "<< tab[i] << endl;
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `mx=tab[1]` is useless in the definition as tab[1] has never been given a value. You probably want `mx=tab[1]` after your first for loop where you load values into tab. Actually, there is more wrong with your attempt to get the closest to average entry.

Comment: Your cout for the closest to average value should be after you find it, which would be after the loop where you are scanning tab to locate it. When you are doing the scanning for closest value, you need to track/save both the smallest difference seen and either the value or its position in tab.

Comment: "...and which entered number is closer to the average" closer than what? What was the aim when you wrote `if (s < mx)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Averaging and closest are amiss.
Initialization of `mx=tab[1]` before reading the entries is bad.

To find the average, perform `b=sum/6;` after the loop.

```
for ( int i=0 ; i<6 ; i++){
    sum=sum+tab[i];
    // b=sum/6;
}
b = sum/6; // Now calculate the average
```

*Closest* is amiss.  Instead,

1. After finding the average, set closest to `mx = abs(tab[0] - b);`
2. Loop and look for better.

```
for ( int i=1 /* not 0 */ ; i < 6; i++){
  float s = abs(tab[i] - b); 
  if (s < mx) {
    mx = s;
  } 
  // No need to print anything yet.
  // cout<<" the number much close to the avg is : "<< tab[i] << endl;
}

// Now print
cout << "The number closest to the average is: " << tab[i] << endl;
```